# How does the following code work for Matrix Multiplication in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do a matrix multiplication in python I have found the following code that I am trying to understand. (I know how to multiply matrices by hand and I want to understand how the following code performs the same action and by that i mean the first element in BA (row 1 column 1) is calculated by doing (1*1 + 3*3 + 3*3 + 1*1) etc.

```
from numpy import array
A= array([[ 1, 4, 5 ],[ 3, 2, 9], [ 3,6, 2], [ 1,6, 8]])
B=A.T

BA= array([[ 0, 0, 0 ],[ 0,0, 0], [ 0,0, 0] ])

for i in range(len(B)):
   for j in range(len(A[0])):
       for k in range(len(A)):
           BA[i][j] += B[i][k] * A[k][j]
```

I know that the length command for a list returns how many elements there are in that list. I am not sure how it works here since B is a matrix, I assume it returns how many rows there are.

range of len(B) would be (0,3) corresponding to row 1,2 and 3. 
for i in range would correspond to i=0, i=1, i= 2

next confusing thing is for j in range len(A[0]) 
The first element of A is the first row, the length here would thus correspond how many elements there are in the first element of A.

Basically I have a basic understanding of what range and len etc put out for this example but I would like to get a better understand of each value of i, j, k as a result of these as well as the last line which I really don't understand.

```
BA[i][j] += B[i][k] * A[k][j]
```

Please explain as basic as possible because I am new to programming and so at this point nothing is trivial to me. Thank you for your time to help others :)

Comment: Is it using `numpy.array`?

Comment: I imported scipy, pylab and sys. not sure what  numpy.array is, if you would like to know what anything returns I can try it out and show you the output.

Comment: You should avoid using the `from module import *` syntax. Not only you might forget which function or class comes from which module, but it can create naming confusion in your program and overriding problems.

Comment: `array` could not be `array.array` from standard libs (it has another signature for construction). It's possible that it is `numpy.array` but it's only hypothesis. Look in your code: do you have `from numpy import ...` somewhere? If so: edit your question and tag accordingly. Please take time and read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration

Comment: B=A.T means matrix B is the transpose of matrix A. I appreciate the advice on avoiding from import. But since I'm at such a basic level I assumed it would be fine and i'm just happy if it works. numpy is included in scipy? is that correct. I've heard you can also use built in"function" from numpy to perform matrix multiplication I'd be interested in how to do that too.

Comment: the T array's method returning the transpose shows it's numpy I think

Comment: btw the code runs and gives the correct output, I just want to understand the code by a description of what it does in english instead of code so i can manipulate it and use it for matrices with different dimensions etc. why is there a concern regarding the array part?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual result from your code:

```
   B    *   A   =      AB
1 3 3 1   1 4 5     20 34 46
4 2 6 6   3 2 9     34 92 98
5 9 2 8   3 6 2     46 98 174
          1 6 8
```

Assuming `i = 0` and `j = 0` lets calculate the `BA[0][0]`, which is the first element from matrix BA.

```
BA[0][0] = B[0][k] * A[k][0]
```

`B[0][k]` means the line 0 from matrix B. As `k` is iterating over all lines of A, which is the same size as the number of columns in B.
`A[k][0]` means the column 0 from matrix A.

The loop `for k in range(len(A)):` will reproduce:

```
B[0][0]*A[0][0] + B[0][1]*A[1][0] + B[0][2]*A[2][0] + B[0][3]*A[3][0]
```

Resulting in:

> 1×1 + 3×3 + 3×3 + 1×1 = 20

Which is the value for `BA[0][0]` resulted from your code.

The following nested loops will iterate over all columns of A as `j` for every line of B as `i` in order to perform the multiplication for all (line) x (column) pairs:

```
for i in range(len(B)):
   for j in range(len(A[0])):
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider here the array as just a more convenient representation of the list you gave to the function.

A is built on top of the list `[[ 1, 4, 5 ],[ 3, 2, 9], [ 3,6, 2], [ 1,6, 8]]`, a list of length 4.

`range(start, stop)` is a function which returns a generator which produces a sequence of integers, from the start to the stop point, stop not being included. If not provided, start defaults to 0.

B has a length of 4 rows so `range(len(B))` will be like `range(0, 3)`, which will produce 0,1 and 2 integers, when "asked" by the for loop. `i` will subsequently be 0,1 and 2.

`A[0]` returns the first row of A, which has a length of 3, so the same way, j will subsequently be 0, 1 and 2 (in this case) ; and k will subsequently be 0, 1, 2 and 3 as A has a length of 4.

BA[i] returns the row of index `i`. Which can also be indexed by `j`
So BA[i][j] is the element of row i and column j, which we increments by the product of the element of row i and index k of matrix B; and the element of row k and index j of matrix A.

Answer (score 0):

In you code sample a matrix is represented a a list of sublists, where each sublist is a row.

So the most outer loop goes over the rows of B:

```
for i in range(len(B)):
```

`A[0]` is the first row of A, and the number of elements in it is the number of A's columns.

So the second loop goes over the columns of A:

```
for j in range(len(A[0])):
```

The most inner loop simply sums the products of the elements in the j-th row of B and the i-th row of A.

```
BA[i][j] += B[i][k] * A[k][j]
```

This add to `BA[i][j]` the product. `+=` adds its right argument to its left one.